# Is there a continuous onto functions between Cantor set and $X$?

Tags: general-topology

$X = \{0,1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, ...\}$. Both Cantor set (denoted as $C$) and $X$ are with Euclidean topology.

So my main concern is that $|X| = |\mathbb{N}|$ and $|C| = |\mathbb{R}|$.

$X$ is compact because it is closed and limited and $C$ is also compact so I believe there should exist continuous onto function $f:C \rightarrow X$. Is my thinking correct?

But there is no onto continuous function $h:X \rightarrow C$ because $|X| = |\mathbb{N}|$ and $|C| = |\mathbb{R}|$. Is this also correct?

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: $[0,1]$ is also compact but there is no continuous onto map $f:[0,1]\to X$. I think the best way to prove the existence of a continuous onto map $f:C\to X$ is to simply define such a map and show that it's continuous.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to define such map.

Comment: Take any non-trivial convergent sequence in $C$ (it's homeomorphic to $X$). Every closed subset is a retract of $C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right on both counts. There *is* a continuous surjection $C \to X$ and there is *not* a continuous surjection $X \to C$.

For the latter, your argument is perfect. $|X| < |C|$, so there cannot exist a surjection $X \to C$.

For the former, I think you have a bit more work to show. You say that "$X$ is compact, and $C$ is compact also, therefore there should exist a continuous surjection $C \to X$", but this idea is wildly untrue. For example, a one point space $\{\star\}$ is compact. Does that mean there is a continuous surjection $\{ \star \} \to X$? Obviously not.

There's a theorem in [descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory) that says

> Every (nonempty) compact metrizable space is a continuous image of $C$

see, for instance Kechris's *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, Theorem 4.18.

Since $X$ is nonempty, compact, and metrizable, your claim follows. So if you're working on a research problem, you're done. If this is homework, etc., I suspect that you're not supposed to be using something this high-powered. So you'll have to basically prove this theorem from scratch (though I don't know of a "simple" proof).

Instead, you might try to directly define a map from $C \to X$. If we identify $C$ with the set of all countable-length binary strings, then we have countable flexibility in how we define our map. For instance, we can partition $C$ into the following sets:

- the first $1$ is in the first position
- the first $1$ is in the second position
- the first $1$ is in the third position
- ...
- the all $0$ string

can you see how to define a surjection $C \to X$ using this decomposition? Can you show that the resulting map is continuous?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: thank you for such a long and comprehensive answer, with this decomposition it is very intuitive how this function will look like. But is this decomposition legal, don't we lose topology structure if we use that?

Comment: Happy to help! As for why this function is continuous, I've intentionally left that detail for you ;). What are the preimages of the open sets in $X$ under this map? Can you show they're open in $C$?

Comment: So for example $f^{-1}(2) =$  set of all countable-length binary strings where first $1$ is in second place. I do not know how to prove that it is an open set in $C$. I do not know what sets are open in $C$. I know that in $X$ every point except $\{0\}$ is isolated, but in $C$ there are no isolated points(or maybe only $\{0\}$ is isolated- i do not know that).

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what theorem the first part is referencing,

It's not true in general that $\exists f$ continuous between any compact sets, take for example $[0,1]$ and $\{0,1\}$, then both sets are compact but one is connected and the other isn't.

It is true that there is no onto function $h : X \to C$ due to cardinality

And I believe you could also construct a function $C \to X$ for example you could use the fact that $\frac{1}{3^n} \in C$ and take the function

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\min(\frac{- \log 3}{\log x}, 1), & \text{if $x \lt 1$} \\
1, & \text{if $x=1$} \\
0, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$

So that $f(\frac{1}{3^n}) = \frac{1}{n}$, $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$